# GTM 2.0: How to fire code before/after main script?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get my head around the after/before options in the Google Tag Manager system, and for an example, I want to set a custom goal in [Clicky](https://clicky.com).

I created 3 **tags**

- After Clicky
- Before Clicky
- Clicky Analytics

**Clicky Analytics** fires in every page where **After Clicky** only executes after the main tag (Clicky Analytics) fires, and **Before Clicky** the reverse.

[image]

and main tag:

[image]

the tags:

[image]

and the result is this:

[image]

Why not in the correct flow? as

- **before**
- **main tag**
- **after**

In Google Tag Manager 1.0, we could specify a wait time (as the calls are async, maybe the issue is that's to fast), but now we have no such option...

The problem here is that I need to fire javascript code, before the main-tag loads, as per [their documentation](http://s9.postimg.org/57bw71sfj/screenshot_116.png).

Comment: I'm not sure your configuration is as you described. In your screenshot "After Clicky" configures to run the next code: Clicky Analytics.
However you should configure "after Clicky Analytics fire 'After Clicky'-Tag".

Hope you get what I mean...

Comment: @michaelsinner the point is that the tag should never come first in the console.output it should be between after/before (or before/after)...

Answer (score 1):

You're tags are firing exactly when you're telling them to, so there could be a mistake in your configuration. Here's an alternative which I just tested and these are my configurations and the results:

**Before**
[image]

**Main**
[image]

**After**
[image]

What you'll notice is that the Before and After tags have no trigger, and the Main tag is set to fire on all pages, and also has both `Setup` and `Cleanup` tags. If you do it this way, you will get your desired output:

[image]

Comment: so your idea is to have `before` and `after` scripts without any trigger, but only setup as after/before the main tag... I can see it works in your side, but that does not work at all in mine ... preview does not even show the tag's without being fired, they are simply not there, and no `console` or `dataLayer` info as well :/

Comment: got what you did ... instead of setting up in after/before tags, you set up the setup/cleanup in the main tag itself... works as intended, but does not apply to my problem as I now have 3 tags (that should fire before the main tag, depending on a variable in the dataLayer)... I will have to add all in just one big script that actually checks and validates the dataLayer it self :/ ... more work

Comment: Are you able to chain the setup and cleanup of the 3 tags that are to fire before your main tag? I was also thinking that a possible alternative (and I haven't tested this out) is to push an event to the dataLayer at the end of the tags, and then the trigger for the other tags would be that dataLayer event.